# Path Summary for PPC campaign visitors

Tags: google-analytics

I have linked my adwords account with my analytics account, so now i can see under sources, that I am getting visitors from "google (ppc)".

Can anyone guide me through on how to create a custom report that will show the Path Summary only for my PPC visitors?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by applying the preconfigured advanced segment for "Paid Search".
2. In the Content section, click "Top Landing Pages". This lists all of your entrance points for paid search visitors.
3. To view the navigation path for each of those entrances, click the URL
4. Then select "Entrances Paths"

This will allow you to drill down into the path that paid search visitors take for each landing page URL.